# jquery-ui retrieving selected in a buttonset (checkbox) - firefox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox

It's possible to retrieve the 'selected' buttons in a jquery ui buttonset build with checkboxes (to allow multiselect) with :

```
$('#format').buttonset();

$('#format').click(function() {
  var text = "";
  $('#format').find('label[aria-pressed|="true"]').each(function() {
      text += $(this).attr("for") + "-";
  });
  $('#selected').html(text); 
});
```

This is working fine in Chrome, IE, Safari but in Firefox the clicked checkbox is not taken into account. You can check this in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tH7F6/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$('label.ui-state-active')
```

See my updated jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qLWNd/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the function bind

```
$('#format').bind("click",function() {
  var text = "";
  $('#format').find('label[aria-pressed|="true"]').each(function() {
      text += $(this).attr("for") + "-";
  });
  $('#selected').html(text); 
});
```

or the live plugin from jquery

Answer (score 0):

FYI, from jquery-ui 1.10.0 to 1.11.4 (latest) the click() event doesn't work as expected for checkboxes buttonset in Firefox.

Try:

```
$('#format').change(function () {
    var text = "";
    $(this).children('label.ui-state-active').each(function () {
      text += $(this).attr("for") + "-";
    });
    $("#selected").html(text);
});
```

See this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/03ee1m60/2/